# MaterialUi without using React

Tags: material-ui

My Question is can we use materialIUI without React? if yes then is it CDN or any other way

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.0.1/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could get Material UI working without React/JSX (to some minimal extent), but it's going to be a **very** challenging process. It would not be a matter of importing Material UI from a CDN and adding class names to your HTML elements.

If you need a Material Design themed framework, [Materialize](https://github.com/dogfalo/materialize) is an open source alternative written in Vanilla JS/CSS/HTML (no React needed).